# Javascript: check formatted date value against current date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

a text-input contains a german formatted date `15.09.2012`
I simply use `$('#wr_event_date').val()` to query the value in the input-field.

I wonder how I can match that date agains "today"?

```
var eventDate = $('#wr_event_date').val();

   // if eventDate is older than today as in "is over" doSomething();
```

So basically I want to check if the eventDate is older than today and if so I want to doSomething();

Ideas on that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would not rely on the client to have a proper date configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to parse the date yourself. Then, fetch the current date with `new Date()`, reset the *time* part, and compare both dates:

```
var s = $('#wr_event_date').val().split(".");
var eventDate = new Date(s[2], s[1] - 1, s[0]);

var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // reset time

if (eventDate.getTime() - today.getTime() < 0) { // event date is older than today
  doSomething();
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qL5JA/)**.

Answer (score 0):

If you could use a third party library, then [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) provides the functions to parse date strings and manipulate dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
var parts = '15.09.2012'.split('.')
var date = Date.parse(parts[1], parts[0] - 1, parts[2]);

if (date - new Date().getTime() > 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) ...
​
```